# Elastic Google Container Engine cluster?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

When you create a Google Container Engine (GKE) cluster you specify what the number and what types of machines you want to use in the cluster.

1. Is it possible to auto-scale the number of cluster machines based on (for example) CPU load?
2. If this is not supported, is there a reason why or is Google working on something like this for the future?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it is. To attach an autoscaler to your existing GKE cluster:

1. Find the name of your cluster's instance group:

   ```
   $ gcloud compute instance-groups managed list
   NAME                         ZONE          BASE_INSTANCE_NAME          SIZE TARGET_SIZE INSTANCE_TEMPLATE            AUTOSCALED
   gke-buildlets-69898e2d-group us-central1-f gke-buildlets-69898e2d-node 1    1           gke-buildlets-69898e2d-1-1-3 yes
   ```

   Here I have a GKE cluster named *buildlets*, and its instance group is named *gke-buildlets-6989e2d-group*
2. Enable autoscaling. This particular example will scale on a target CPU utilization of 70%:

   ```
   gcloud compute instance-groups managed set-autoscaling YOUR_INSTANCE_GROUP_NAME \
     --zone=YOUR_INSTANCE_GROUP_ZONE \
     --min-num-replicas=1 \
     --max-num-replicas=8 \
     --scale-based-on-cpu \
     --target-cpu-utilization=.7
   ```

You can also use [Google Cloud Deployment manager](https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/overview) to create your GKE cluster, and create/attach an autoscaler right along with it:

```
resources:
- name: buildlets
  type: container.v1.cluster
  properties:
    zone: us-central1-f
    cluster:
      initial_node_count: 1
      network: "default"
      logging_service: "logging.googleapis.com"
      monitoring_service: "monitoring.googleapis.com"
      node_config:
        machine_type: n1-standard-1
        oauth_scopes: 
          - "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"
      master_auth: 
        username: admin
        password: password123
- name: autoscaler
  type: compute.v1.autoscaler
  properties:
    zone: us-central1-f
    name: buildlets
    target: "$(ref.buildlets.instanceGroupUrls[0])"
    autoscalingPolicy: 
      minNumReplicas: 2
      maxNumReplicas: 8
      coolDownPeriodSec: 600 
      cpuUtilization: 
        utilizationTarget: .7`
```

Comment: It is not recommended according to gke FAQ: https://github.com/kubernetes/autoscaler/blob/master/cluster-autoscaler/FAQ.md#should-i-use-a-cpu-usage-based-node-autoscaler-with-kubernetes

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to manually [resize a GKE cluster](https://cloud.google.com/container-engine/docs/resize-cluster), yes. AFAIK you'd need to do the 'elastic' part yourself ATM, for example based on Heapster output.

Comment: I was referring to "auto-scaling", sorry for not being explicit about that (I've updated the question now). Thanks for the pointer to Heapster.

Comment: No worries, I understood it that way. That's why I said auto-scale (or 'elastic') is ATM not supported ;)

Appreciate upvote if you think it helped …

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely create an autoscaler that automatically chooses and sets the number of pods that run in a kubernetes cluster. So the autoscaler will be created and will be using the replication controller as a reference to automatically increase or decrease the number of pods as needed. You can have more information in this [Help Center article](https://cloud.google.com/container-engine/docs/kubectl/autoscale).